# npm WARN @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.0 but none was installed

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angular-cli

I have install latest nodejs version `v7.9.0`, `angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3`, `npm version: 4.5.0`.
However, when I use `npm install --save @angular/material`, it displays some warnings

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of @angular/common@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of @angular/http@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
```

I don't know how to update my `@angular/core` to `@^4.0.0`. Currently in my dependencies file it is `^2.3.1`

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    }
```

I think all of my tool is latest so what I do wrong? And how can I fix it?. I am new to Angularjs+Material, any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either one of these

```
npm install @angular/core@latest --save
```

In the time of writing it will be 4.1.0, but you can [check it here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/core)

**or**

```
npm install @angular/core@x.x.x --save
```

Where x.x.x is the desired version.

**or**

Change the version manually within the package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
...
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0",0
}
```

and run `npm install`

**This is a major version update**, so be sure to check the [update guide](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/) if needed.